problem about a graph

Let G a graph of order n and $C_k$ a cycle of order $k$ in $G$ , where $n\geq k\geq 4$
.A chord of $C_k$ is an edge in $G$ with joins two non-consecutive vertices along $C_k$

Let $G$ a graph of order $n\geq 4$ , if $e(G)=|E(G)|\geq 2n-3$ , then $G$ contains a cycle with a chord
(initially I have thought to consider (proof by contradiction )a maximal cycle  $C$ in $G$ (with exists because $ n-1<2n-3$)and then, to edge the cycle with additional cycles (without disturbing the criterion(of not having a chord )), or through branches, and arrive at a contradiction regarding the number of vertices obtained by having reached such a structure endowed with the required number of edges (based on the initially imposed value of $n$)But all of this appears rather vague, and I’m unsure how to concretize it to reach a proper proof. Could someone kindly provide guidance on how to prove such an assertion?

This is related to (and possibly a duplicate of) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84309/715329

You might also find this useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/454907/715329

@Pranay it is indeed a duplicate
